# Getting Error while overriding excel(xls) file (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
//
//Other stuff here
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(location);
workbook.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();
```

First time this code works fine, but I need to override the file with the same name when the user request so.
But when my program enters in to this loop again, it give the following error:

```
The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open
```

And when I try to open the file manually, it give me a pop up showing file is locked.

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: Apache POI 3.14

Comment: I am actually doing this stuff in a Thread(which keeps repeating itself after 30 seconds). I check whether new data is available and if it is I overwrite the file with new Data.   
Could this be a problem?
Because the same thread reports the error while overwriting.

Comment: Are you re-opening the existing file,  or re-creating from scratch? And are you closing the Workbook?